# How to get exact property meant by infamous "trying to get property of non-object" error message?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5 gives out this exact error message every time an unknown property is used somewhere in a view, it's probably one of the most seen error messages ever:

```
trying to get property of non-object
```

**The Problem:**
Laravel does NEVER say **which property** of **which object**. This is insane! Even plain PHP clearly says the exact point of failure, but Laravel does not.

So the question is, how to find out the exact object/property behind this error ?

Comment: @MarkBaker Done for sure, but this is the problem: The nearest information is the name/path of the view file! No info on line, method, object etc. inside!

Comment: and laravel is using compiled views, so, there is no way to know. You can get close if you open the compiled view.. The name of it will be something like "5569f01652ce2cc009a97a5a27176063 line X". You will not see explicitily the error  but this can give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does NEVER say you this, but You can use **`dd()`** in the view multiple time at different step. So, you can get where was the problem.